# Spinner Element not showing proper view before selection

Tags: android, alignment, spinner

enter image description here[I have 4 Spinner, After selection first spinner second spinner item will come.When I open the page it shows like image,first one text is in proper position but third element have some gap,when I choose my item of first one then second one automatically take one of its list and there have no gap which I mentioned in image.  Please help me regarding this.

This spinner in my layout

```
    <Spinner

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:entries="@array/subloc"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            />
```

Spinner item is:

```
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:text="dvvdv"/>
```

]

[image]

Comment: Try to remove space from your string of "Select Subnature" or remove padding from raw file of that spinner.

Comment: Do not have any left padding

Comment: Before setting Spinner prompt trim the content and set.

Comment: Are you using same views for all spinners ?

Comment: Android monitor has Layout Inspector, with that you can easily find the problem. It will give all information about your view. From that you can obtain the origin of that gap.

Comment: Android Monitor......Where I get this option in Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:**
Try to use default **android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item** for spinner drop down it will show perfectly without any space 
orelse

**//Step2**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
   android:hint="Select item"
   android:background="@drawable/spin"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have different text style.

Comment: I have a problem with spinner item,not with dropdown item

Comment: @Trisha..oh that's cool ...if you got solution please vote for me :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Spinner Item like the below.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="dvvdv"/>
```

Comment: I dnt have problem with bottom or top,I have problem with left,before selection.If I select parent item then child item showing in perfect view

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have added space before ***Select Subnature*** *String*. Try to remove that space.

Comment: No,I did not add any space